# How to get number of times letter repeated in list

Tags: python

I have a scenario where i want to print the number of times the letter repeated in lst

```
my_lst =['AVBXXX' , 'GAHJJKSL' ]
```

**My Output should be like below :**

**List :** `AVBXXX`

```
A - 1
V - 1
B - 1
X - 3
```

**List :** `GAHJJKSL`

```
G - 1
A - 1
H - 1
J - 2
K - 1
S - 1
L - 1
```

**My code :**

```
getlen=len(lst)

lettercnt=0
for i in range(lst):
    v=lst[i] 
    print("List :",v)
    for j in str(v):
       if j =='A'
           lettercnt+=1
       elif j =='V'
           lettercnt+=1
       elif j =='B'
           lettercnt+=1  
        elif j =='X'
           lettercnt+=1
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: What about `def letter_freq(string):
    return {letter: string.count(letter) for letter in set(string)}`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter

my_lst =['AVBXXX' , 'GAHJJKSL' ]

{l : Counter(l) for l in my_lst}
```

Output:

```
{'AVBXXX': Counter({'A': 1, 'V': 1, 'B': 1, 'X': 3}),
 'GAHJJKSL': Counter({'G': 1, 'A': 1, 'H': 1, 'J': 2, 'K': 1, 'S': 1, 'L': 1})}
```

If you want to get the exact desired output try this:

```
dct = {l : Counter(l) for l in my_lst}

for k,v in dct.items():
    print(f'lits:{k}')
    for i,j in v.items():
        print(f'{i}:{j}')
```

Output:

```
lits:AVBXXX
A:1
V:1
B:1
X:3
lits:GAHJJKSL
G:1
A:1
H:1
J:2
K:1
S:1
L:1
```

Answer (score -1):

For better understanding, iterate over the list of items. Then use a dictionary to find out the frequency of the list item.

```
my_lst =['AVBXXX' , 'GAHJJKSL' ]

for lst in my_lst:
    my_dict={}
    for l in lst:
        if l in my_dict:
            my_dict[l]+=1
        else:
            my_dict[l]=1
    print(lst, my_dict)
```

Output

```
AVBXXX {'A': 1, 'V': 1, 'B': 1, 'X': 3}
GAHJJKSL {'G': 1, 'A': 1, 'H': 1, 'J': 2, 'K': 1, 'S': 1, 'L': 1}
```

If you want to get more pythonic way then you can use also groupby

```
from itertools import groupby
for lst in my_lst:
    results = {value: len(list(freq)) for value, freq in groupby(sorted(lst))}
    print(results)
```